# Mouse.Synchronize()

Tags: c#, .net

What does Mouse.Synchronize() do in .Net?

MSDN says it 'forces the mouse to resynchronize'

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.synchronize.aspx ... hmmm, not the best documentation ever: "Forces the mouse to resynchronize."

Comment: There's some remarks about MouseDevice.Synchronize() on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousedevice.synchronize.aspx

Comment: Looks like Microsoft should add more info to it..

what i assume that it has something to do with resetting frequency the polling of mouse and match it with frequency of OS..

Though i am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my assumption:

Similar method exists in [Stylus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.aspx) class: [Stylus.Synchronize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.synchronize.aspx). It should be used together with [Stylus.DirectlyOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.directlyover.aspx) to ensure that stylus pointer is still above button, although the button was moved somewhere else.

I believe that **"Synchronize" is implemented in parent class of both classes: *Stylus* and *Mouse*. It's important for Stylus, but it's not necessary for the Mouse.** I tried example from [Stylus.Synchronize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.synchronize.aspx) ( I just replaced "Stylus" by "Mouse" ) and it works well also without Mouse.Synchronize(); line.

Comment: Thanks. In WPF there is the Thumb class where I think this might be useful. Sometimes when doing drag operation for a thumb if the conditions don't allow the thumb to move further and user keeps dragging, dragdelta goes berserk. I think this might be quite useful there. Infact the very reason for asking was I had a hunch it might be doing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for what it's worth here is the source code of the method:

```cs
public void Synchronize()
{
    PresentationSource criticalActiveSource = this.CriticalActiveSource;
    if (((criticalActiveSource != null) && (criticalActiveSource.CompositionTarget != null)) && !criticalActiveSource.CompositionTarget.IsDisposed)
    {
        InputReportEventArgs args;
        int tickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        Point clientPosition = this.GetClientPosition();
        RawMouseInputReport report = new RawMouseInputReport(InputMode.Foreground, tickCount, criticalActiveSource, RawMouseActions.AbsoluteMove, (int) clientPosition.X, (int) clientPosition.Y, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        report._isSynchronize = true;
        if (this._stylusDevice != null)
        {
            args = new InputReportEventArgs(this._stylusDevice, report);
        }
        else
        {
            args = new InputReportEventArgs(this, report);
        }
        args.RoutedEvent = InputManager.PreviewInputReportEvent;
        this._inputManager.Value.ProcessInput(args);
    }
}
```

The important line is:

```
RawMouseInputReport report = new RawMouseInputReport(InputMode.Foreground, tickCount, criticalActiveSource, RawMouseActions.AbsoluteMove, (int) clientPosition.X, (int) clientPosition.Y, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

According to this, the method is trying to move the mouse to the same position it's already in then analyze the results - here comes my own assumption, that if there's any offset between the previous position and new position, it's stored somewhere and used for any future mouse actions.